# How to change the JMS broker memory settings

Tags: java, jvm, glassfish, memory-management, jms

I am trying to figure out how to change the JMS brokers JVM memory settings on Glassfish 2.1. When the server instance starts it automatically starts up the broker, how do I adjust the memory allocation? I found a little help at this site http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1794/aeokk?l=en&a=view but it only shows you how to adjust the memory allocation from the command line. I found the configuration file that it mentions but I can't figure out how to pass it the vmargs. Any help with this would be great.
Thanks,
Brody Smith

Comment: I think you can do it in the admin console under Configuration->Java Messaging Service->start arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the admin console click on Configuration ~ Java Message Service (just as user364939 suggests). Then in the "Start Arguments" field enter

```
-vmargs -Xmx512m
```

or whatever memory settings you need.